# How to create a tessellation with turtles in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, tessellation

I'm trying to create a rhombus tessellation pattern with the turtle graphics on python that looks like this image:

http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/coloring_medium/public/cif/2015/01/tessellation-with-rhombus-coloring-pages.png

I thought about creating a hexagon pattern first and then dividing the hexagons into thirds. I'm not sure how I can create the hexagon pattern recursively. So far, I'm only alternating the angles of the turtles as I run the program and I don't have a definite strategy. Any advice on how to approach this?

So far, I created 3 hexagons in the center with 3 turtles and used for loops to draw the hexagons around the 3 hexagons. However, when I loop the program, the turtles trace back the same path as before and it takes a while for it to draw the others.

Here is my code so far:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.left(120)
t2.left(240)
for i in (t, t1, t2):
    i.speed(0)

def hex():
    for b in (t, t1, t2):
        for i in range(6):
             b.forward(100)
             b.right(60)


for i in range(3):
    t.left(120)
hex()
def rep():   
    for i in range(3):
        for a in (t, t1, t2):
            a.forward(100)
            a.right(60)
            for i in range(6):
                a.forward(100)
                a.left(60)
rep()

def rep2():
    for a in (t, t1, t2):
        for i in range(3):
            a.left(120)
            a.forward(100)
            a.right(60)
            rep()

    a.right(120)
    a.forward(100)
    a.right(60)
    rep()
rep2()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many of drawing this. I would draw based the rhombus shape because it will allow you to fill them with different colors. To be able to fill each rhombus, it needs to be drawn individually. The figure contains three different rhombus shapes (they are the same rhombus in different orientation).
I will draw first row and second row. After that it is repetition of the first and second row. Here is code:

```
def draw_rhombus(x,y,degree,size,tilt,color):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.seth(tilt)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.pencolor('dark gray')
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.fd(size)
    turtle.left(degree)
    turtle.fd(size)
    turtle.left(180-degree)
    turtle.fd(size)
    turtle.left(degree)
    turtle.fd(size)
    turtle.left(180-degree)
    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_rhombus_1(x,y,size):
    draw_rhombus(x,y,120,size,0,'red')

def draw_rhombus_2(x,y,size):
    draw_rhombus(x,y,60,size,0,'green')

def draw_rhombus_3(x,y,size):
    draw_rhombus(x,y,60,size,60,'blue')

def rt_row_1(startx,starty,size,n):
    x = startx
    y = starty
    for i in range(n):
        draw_rhombus_1(x,y,size)
        x += size
        draw_rhombus_3(x,y,size)
        draw_rhombus_2(x,y,size)
        x += 2*size

def rt_row_2(startx,starty,size,n):
    x = startx
    y = starty
    for i in range(n):
        draw_rhombus_2(x,y,size)
        x += 2*size
        draw_rhombus_1(x,y,size)
        x += size
        draw_rhombus_3(x,y,size)

size = 80
x = -400
y = -400
for i in range(800//int(round(size*math.sqrt(3)))):
    rt_row_1(x,y,size,800//(size*3))
    rt_row_2(x-size/2,y+size*math.sqrt(3)/2,size,800//(size*3))
    y += size*math.sqrt(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify your three turtle, three function hexagonal tessellation to a single turtle, single *recursive* function solution:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

OUTER_RADIUS = 100
INNER_RADIUS = 3**0.5 * OUTER_RADIUS / 2
SIDES = 6
EXTENT = 360 / SIDES

def tessellation(depth):
    turtle.right(EXTENT/2)

    for _ in range(SIDES):
        turtle.circle(OUTER_RADIUS, EXTENT, 1)

        if depth:
            heading = turtle.heading()

            turtle.right(90)
            tessellation(depth - 1)

            turtle.setheading(heading)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-OUTER_RADIUS / 2, -INNER_RADIUS)
turtle.pendown()
tessellation(2)

screen.tracer(True)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

(Increase the `depth` argument to fill the window.)  The tessellation you really want is four (not thirds) of these patterns overlaid atop each other.  Keeping our initial code the same:

```
screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience

turtle.penup()
turtle.color('blue')
turtle.goto(OUTER_RADIUS / 4, -1 * INNER_RADIUS / 2)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setheading(0)
tessellation(2)

turtle.penup()
turtle.color('red')
turtle.goto(-OUTER_RADIUS / 2, -2 * INNER_RADIUS / 2)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setheading(0)
tessellation(2)

turtle.penup()
turtle.color('yellow')
turtle.goto(OUTER_RADIUS / 4, -3 * INNER_RADIUS / 2)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setheading(0)
tessellation(2)

turtle.penup()
turtle.color('green')
turtle.goto(-OUTER_RADIUS / 2, -4 * INNER_RADIUS / 2)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setheading(0)
tessellation(2)

screen.tracer(True)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]